# Random String in linux by system time

Tags: linux, random

I work with Bash. I want to generate randrom string by system time . The length of the unique string must be between 10 and 30 characters.Can anybody help me?

Comment: So is it random? Or somehow determined by system time?

Comment: In what language? C, C++, Bash, Python, Perl?

Comment: how about `date | md5`

Comment: I have  updated question,please see it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, my favorite one using the `urandom` device:

```
burhan@sandbox:~$ tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w30 | head -n1
CCI4zgDQ0SoBfAp9k0XeuISJo9uJMt
```

- `tr` (translate) makes sure that only alphanumerics are shown
- `fold` will wrap it to 30 character width
- `head` makes sure we get only the first line

To use the current system time (as you have this specific requirement):

```
burhan@sandbox:~$ date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c30; echo
NDc0NGQxZDQ4MWNiNzBjY2EyNGFlOW
```

- `date +%s` = this is our date based seed
- We run it through a few hashes to get a "random" string
- Finally we truncate it to 30 characters

Other ways (including the two I listed above) are available at [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/) and others if you simply [google](http://google.com/search?q=generate+random+string+linux).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use [`uuidgen -t`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_uuidgen.htm).

> Generate a time-based UUID. This method creates a UUID based on the system clock plus the system's ethernet hardware address, if present.

Comment: Thanks.But it must be between 10 and 30

Comment: 1b4e28ba-2fa1-11d2-883f-b9a761bde3fb: 32 digits (not counting the slashes). You could use Base32 encoding instead of Base16.

Answer (score 0):

I recently put together a script to handle this, the output is 33 digit md5 checksum but you can trim it down with sed to between 10-30.

E.g. `gen_uniq_id.bsh | sed 's/\(.\{20\}\)\(.*$\)/\1/'`

The script is fairly robust - it uses current time to nanoseconds, /dev/urandom, mouse movement data and allows for optionally changing the collection times for random and mouse data collection.

It also has a -s option that allows an additional string argument to be incorporated, so you can random seed from anything.

https://code.google.com/p/gen-uniq-id/